# Skype 4.3 keeps signing me out in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, skype

I have installed Skype 4.3 last month and all have been working fine until yesterday.The problem is that  I log in in my account and after some seconds it signs me out unexpectedly.I tried some solutions from the web like deleting .Skype file from Home folder or using sqlite3 changing main.db but without any luck.
I’m using Ubuntu 12.04.5.Are there any others having the same problem or is there any solution to this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your account at Skype rather than the client software on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, and did several suggestions from the internet but nothing happened...
Do reinstallation, it works for me though... and do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hope it'll help!